# Variable ODBC DSN name in InstallShield MSI installation

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I'm designing a new MSI installation for a product that allows multiple instances to be installed. Many of the components of the installation are identified by a 2-character code. Among these is an ODBC data source. The name of the data source includes this 2-character code, which is something the user enters during installation. I notice that I cannot use a property name "[MyPropertyName]" as the Name of an ODBC DSN in an InstallShield project. Is there any clean way to allow the ODBC DSN name to be set at runtime? If I were creating hard-wired names for each of my instances, I could create a separate DSN for each hardwired instance name ("Test" and "Production" for example), but we allow the user to specify the name. Am I going to run into more dead-ends as a result of this or is there a way to allow user-specified instance-specific property values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either a) skip the ODBC tables in MSI and use the Registry table instead or b) use a custom action to dynamically inject custom rows at install time into the ODBC tables.

Comment: Is it better (more possible? / cleaner?) to inject custom rows into the ODBC tables than to have a custom action that directly creates ODBC data sources? I wasn't aware the MSI tables could be modified at run-time. Are there any examples of this?

Comment: It's cleaner because you still leverage MSI's standard actions that inherently know how to handle install/uninstall/repair/upgrade/rollback scenarios.  The downside is you temporary data isn't screened by MSI validation at build time.

Comment: See: http://blog.iswix.com/2008/07/dynamic-windows-installer-ui.html    In your scenario I'd just skip the ODBC tables and use the Registry table.  ODBC isn't really that hard... MSI's ODBC support is really just an abstraction of registry data.

Comment: Does the InstallShield registry editor to a better job of allowing property value substitutions in key names than the ODBC editor did? Can I simply use, for example, "My DSN for Instance [MyInstanceIdentity]" in a registry key name to pick up a property value to use in a DSN name?

Comment: It's not really a function of InstallShield, it's a function of Windows Installer's underlying table schema data types.  Text types are static and Formatted types can be formatted using properties.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371168(v=vs.85).aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370546(v=vs.85).aspx  and look at the data type definitions of  RegKey, Text and Formmated.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the un-install. It's uninstalling different registry entries than it installed. I think it's because the instance-specific properties used to create the registry entries are not saved and re-used when the un-install runs, and it's instead picking up default values when running the un-install. How is the un-install supposed to remember what the values of its properties were so it un-installs the same things it installed. I'm kind of surprised that MSI isn't smarter about tracking what it did and undoing whatever that was.

Comment: Correct. MSI doesn't persist properties across transactions.  You have to implement a property persistence pattern.  Alternatively if you are simply trying to isolate the DSNs  then you could do something like  MyDSN-[InstanceId]   InstanceId is baked into the MSI and each instance transform so you don't have to persist it.

Comment: BTW you are also going to find out that unless the component with the registry has a file as a keypath that you are going to need multiple components with different guids and component conditions to be mutually exclusive otherwise you'll be dealing with uninstall / reference counting issues also.

Comment: I'm still getting some very confusing behavior during uninstall. None of the registry entries get removed until the uninstall of the last instance. Then only the registry entries for that instance get removed. I tried turning the "Shared" property on the "ISRegistryComponent" that was generated for these registry actions to "No", but that seemed to have no effect. Should I replace one of the digits of the Component Code GUID with [InstanceId]?

Comment: This is what I was trying to tell you in my previous comment. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367797(v=vs.85).aspx "•To keep the nonfile data of each instance isolated, the base package should collect nonfile data into sets of components for each instance. The appropriate components should then be installed based on conditional statements that depend on the instance identifier."

Comment: The easiest way to deal with this is to make sure all components have a file as their keypath.

Comment: It matters because it matters.  It's just how MSI works.  If the key path was a file and it happened to have a registry resource you would only need 1 component not 3.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something, then, because I added a dummy file to my registry component, made it the Key File, deleted the other 2 duplicate registry components, installed my application twice, manually specifying different INSTALLPATH values during the install process for each installation, and then un-installed the first instance. The dummy file for the first instance went away, but the registry entries did not.

Comment: Clean or dirty machine? Make sure you test on VM snapshots that have never had your product.  I'd have to mock it all up but it should work.

Comment: I created a totally new installer to make sure it was clean. I'm in the process of creating a new VM. This question is too complex to resolve in comments. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190598/best-way-to-uninstall-registry-entries-from-msi-multi-instance-installshield-pac